# Connect data tables from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

Input string was not in a correct format. "Set set1 = new set can't connect to database.
Database table names is Set but I couldn't connect. I'm using ASP.NET C#. Help, please.

```
if (itemName == name)
{
    Set set1 = new Set
    {
        Set_ID = int.Parse(itemId),
        Item_ID = int.Parse(alacarte)
    };
    db.Sets.InsertOnSubmit(set1);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Can you show your database logic as well? Also, check for null before assigning to Set_ID, Item_ID

Comment: @DamienJoe Actually Im using dropdownlist to list all the data from datatables, after that using c# to read selected value, but I still couldn't read the value and store into datatables `int alacarte = int.Parse(ddlAlacarte.SelectedValue);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will get `Input string was not in a correct format` error if `itemId` or `alacarte` may not have valid integer string value.

use `int.TryParse`

```
int no1,no2;
if (int.TryParse(itemId, out no1) && int.TryParse(alacarte, out no2))
{
    Set set1 = new Set
    {
        Set_ID = no1,
        Item_ID = no2
    };
    db.Sets.InsertOnSubmit(set1);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```